# how to make footer stick to the bottom of the screen using css

Tags: html, css, cordova

I am making a phonegap app. I am trying to make a tab in the footer and want to stick it at the bottom of the screen so when user scroll down it should stay there and always visible. My current code does display tabs navigation at the bottom but when I scroll then tabs also scrolls up and down. Please help me how can I fix it.

Here is my code

```
<header>
    header
</header>
<section class="contents">
</section>
<footer>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

here is my css

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red; }
  footer .nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%; }
      footer .nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: -0.2em;
      height: 20%;
      padding: 5% 10.7%;
      background: #ccc; }
         footer .nav li a {
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Use fiddle next time (http://jsfiddle.net/7mujA/). What is wrong with this? Footer seems to be sticky at the bottom

Comment: Yes according to code it should be working but on my android it is not sticking.

Comment: Phones struggle with fixed positions see this link: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: Some mobile devices don't support fixed positioning, as @SHTester mentioned.  You can try using a framework that is designed for mobile devices, and includes fixed navs like jQuery Mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a sticky footer in a responsive manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715623/create-a-sticky-footer-in-a-responsive-manner)