# Create a sticky footer in a responsive manner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm trying to create a responsiveness sticky footer but without any success. I have followed every guide and every common best practices. Here it is my example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/exupej61/)

In the example I would put the footer at the bottom of the page.In addition I would use an image as background of the entire page

```
.blur {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

keep your HTML just as is, and change your CSS to this (obviously you'll change it later to your needs, I just added styling for visualization purposes):

```
html, body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family:'Raleway', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    background:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-OSVC5PTEAKU/TZNnUHaoJZI/AAAAAAAAApo/WcP3qSUPAoo/s1600/monta%2525C3%2525B1as%252520verdes%255B1%255D.jpg') no-repeat 50%;
    background-size:cover;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding-bottom:80px /* footer height + 20 px for spacing, but adjust as you like */;
}
a {
    color: #eee;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #dedede;
}
/* Langind Page */
 .inner {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.btn-facebook-inner {
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px;
}
.btn-facebook {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #3B5998;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-family:'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
}
.btn-facebook:hover, .btn-facebook:focus {
    color: #dfe3ee;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#fc0;
}
footer .social-icons > ul > li {
    padding-right: 12px;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcznxv3d/) here

This will make the bottom to be fixed, so if you have a lot of content, the footer will overlap the content. If you don't want this behavior, change `fixed` to `absolute`

Just a comment I have seen on your code and see as a recurrent error around here: while it's common to target html and body together, they're **NOT** the same thing and not all styles applies to both

Comment: This solution seems working in a desktop display but when I use in the mobile it doesn't work. it shoes me some white borders

Comment: you probably have some additional CSS affecting the output, in general mobile have a 19px padding definition, so try adding padding:0 to body (if it doesn't work try adding !important)

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this and went a different way.  If you are inherently setting a "height" value for the footer,  while your footer will still "respond", the background follows the styling and will only display at "n px" leaving you with the body color below.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

**HTML:**

```
<body>


   <div id="wrap">



    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
   /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
   height: 60px;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

**Edit**
**HTML**

```
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="blur">

  <!-- Begin page content -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 inner">
                <h1 class="text-center">Title</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 btn-facebook-inner">
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-facebook center-block">Login with Facebook</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-9 social-icons">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>Facebook</li>
                    <li>Instagram</li>
                    <li>Twitter</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-md-pull-3">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>Privacy Policy</li>
                    <li>Terms of Use</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}


#blur {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
 /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
 /* Pad bottom by footer height */
 padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```